# How to set customized tabstop color for a button in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, tabstop

I have placed a background image on my windows application form and when tab stops to a particular button it's color is changed and looks awkward...Can anyone tell me that how can I set some customized color for tabstop or set its value to null????

---

I've tried the answer from BalaR i.e. button.ShowFocusCues =  falase in load event of the form but it says that it can't be used like this and it is protected

Answer (score 0):

<strike>try [`ShowFocusCues`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.showfocuscues.aspx) to false</strike>

```
button.ShowFocusCues = false;
```

to hide focus rectangle.

I didn't notice it was a protected member. You have two options

- use reflection to set the protected member (not recommended)
- create a derived class and set the protected member as you'd like. (the right way)

  ```
  class MyButton : Button
  {
      protected override bool ShowFocusCues
      {
          get { return false; }
      }
  }
  ```

You can also set [`TabStop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabstop.aspx) to false.

```
button.TabStop = false;
```

if you don't want the button to obtain focus during tab cycle.

Comment: I've tried the above thing i.e. button.ShowFocusCues = falase in load event of the form but it says that it can't be used like this and it is protected

Comment: @Taha Khan see my edit. I'll try to post code snippets if you need some help.

Comment: Do i need to create this derived class at some form and give it public access or i will have to make it in some separate module???